# Registration confusion Android GCM

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to migrate to `GCM` in Android, `C2DM` now being deprecated. The registration process described [here](http://pages.citebite.com/f2y6h7i3usfy) is different from registration described [here](http://pages.citebite.com/i2v6c5g5tkjr). Are both registration same? Can we see code for `GCMRegistrar` to know for sure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are actually the same thing. The second one encapsulates the first one in a static method and registers a broadcast receiver. You can attach the source to the gcm.jar and see for yourself. You can find source code in ~/android-sdks/extras/google/gcm/gcm-client/gcm-src.jar

Answer (score 6):

I've successfully migrated my C2DM project to GCM. Tested, it works fine. The only changes were:

- in the Android app - change the value of `sender` upon registration
- on the server side - change the auth header and the URL

That was it, as far as the interaction with Google goes. There were more some changes dictated by the app's logic:

- in the Android app, the registration ID was cached in its preferences. Upon upgrade, I remove reg ID from the preferences to force re-registration, this time with GCM.
- the logic of passing the reg ID to the server got an extra boolean parameter - if this is a C2DM or GCM reg ID
- the logic of sending messages became conditional upon the said parameter.

Throwing out the C2DM logic completely out of the server would be unwise - not everyone upgrades their Android apps. The old, C2DM-enabled versions will be out in the wild for some time. And Google pledged to keep C2DM running in the short term. So message sending is conditional - depending on reg ID type, it sends either to GCM or to C2DM.

EDIT re: conditional logic:

```
if($RegID_Is_GCM)
{
    $Auth = GCM_Auth();
    $URL = $GCM_URL;
}
else
{
    $Auth = C2DM_AUTH();
    $URL = $C2DM_URL;
}
```

Comment: hi, what does "the logic of sending messages became conditional upon the said parameter." mean?

Answer (score 1):

The Thing I like most in GCM is the **RegID** we will get from GCM server,it is not only an ID its an Address of this application on this Device. So this time you don't need to send a device Id to server along with your *Registration Id* as per was in C2DM.

In C2DM every time you request a registration id you will get a new ID.

But in GCM RegId generated by using your **application package** along with **some device id** so if you will request for Registration Id again and again you will receive the *same RegId.*

**And if you uninstall an application and will install it again still GCM server will give you the same Registration Id.**

So one Registraion Id will do no need of any Device Id to send to server.

Answer (score 0):

GCMRegistrar is just a helper that does the leg work described in the first page.

You can see the class here. `android-sdk\extras\google\gcm\gcmclient\src\com\google\android\gcm`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been successful at migrating from C2DM to GCM. I have also documented how to implement GCM at 
http://android.amolgupta.in/2012/07/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-tutorial.html