# Can an android work on both GCM and C2DM?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app that currently uses C2DM for push notifications. I would like to inquire if I update the app to GCM and if some users do not upgrade their app, will Google allow me to use both the C2DM and GCM for the two versions of my app?

Or will the users on my previous app never receive a PUSH notification altough I still have the push logic implemented for C2DM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've completely replaced C2DM with GCM in the app, and left support for both protocols in the server side. Works like a charm; details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260364/registration-confusion-android-gcm/11263828#11263828).

Answer (score 1):

They will still receive them as long as you don't remove any authorisation keys, ids etc. as GCM uses the Project ID while C2DM uses the registered e-mail address.

More on it here: [C2DM to GCM Migration](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html)

Answer (score 1):

Once the C2DM service was deprecated recently I advice you to migrate your pushes system to GCM service.

The best way to deal with it is doing the thing like Google says. Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html#interop) topic in the official GCM's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

While not the original question, an interesting one would be: Can one app simultaneously use C2DM and GCM.

C2DM uses the Sender-Account while GCM uses the Project-ID to register. The only thing they both might share is the App-package name (and obviously the google account of the device, but that shouldn't matter as there are multiple apps which can use gcm/c2dm in parallel anyway).

In my experience registering C2DM and GCM in the same app can cause some serious problems.

Reason to have both in one app might be that you want to use GCM in the app, but can't everywhere because a legacy backend might not be able to switch to GCM yet. Probably a rather rare scenario - but currently happening for our app.

Comment: If I may ask, what are some of the modifications you have been asked to make to handle this scenario? Do you see any major customer impacts?

Comment: We connect to 2 different backend systems. One is deployed only once a year in production. The other monthly. So we wanted to migrate to gcm with one of them while still having to support c2dm for the other one.