# Migrate from C2DM to GCM for a background service

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-c2dm

My app has a bacground service in it, which currently uses C2DM. I want to migrate to GCM.

There are 2 GCM implementations available to me

1: using gcm.jar and replace the C2DM email address with the sender ID

2: use Google Play Services and the GoogleCloudMessaging class to register for GCM

Option 1 above provides the simplest migration path from C2DM to GCM, however, that gcm.jar is deprecated. So I'd be moving from one deprecated push mechanism (C2DM) to another (GCM using the gcm.jar)

Option 2, requires you to check that the GooglePlayServices are up to date on your device before you can register for GCM. You can make the Google Play Services ready for use by calling GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog() api. However, I cant call this api from a background service as it may result in screens being displayed to the user, something which you should not do from a background service.

Currently I have both C2DM and GCM (using Google Play Services) active in my Android client. I would prefer to have just GCM active, and to drop C2DM, but if the Google Play Services are not ready for use on the device, then I cant use GCM. Now I could have a situation where my background service is not registered for GCM and if it had continued to use C2DM it would have be registered for that.

Questions:

1: What is Googles recommended migration path for C2DM->GCM for background services. Should I use the gcm.jar approach, even though its deprecated?

2: If Google Play Services are not currently available on the device, should you fall back to using C2DM, rather than call GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()?

3: Having both C2DM and GCM active in my client is unsatisfactory. When I register for GCM using GoogleCloudMessaging.register(senderId), a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION message is broadcast, which is picked up my my C2DM receiver. I can not tell if the message is a C2DM registration message or a GCM registration message. Is there a way to distinguish between the 2 registration messages? I know that GoogleCloudMessaging.register() returns the registration Id, but it also results in that com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION message being broadcast which seems unnecessary and confuses the real C2DM receiver.

I welcome your advise / insight into my problem. The documentation around Google Play services seems a little light and does not address its use from background services.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the recommended migration path, but here's one that worked for me: [Registration confusion Android GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260364/registration-confusion-android-gcm/11263828#11263828)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This migration example is to GCM using gcm.jar, and not Google Play Services. I know that I can use this form of GCM in my background service, but its deprecated. I was wondering how to move over to Google Play Services. Maybe I cant use Google Play Services 100% from a background service, given that I cant guide the user through enabling it, by calling getErrorDialog().

Comment: I'm not using gcm.jar on the server. I'm using raw HTTP requests with Curl inside PHP. The HTTP protocol is simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

The code from the example in the documentation should be sufficient to check the Play Services:

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(GCMTAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Only if the result is not ConnectionResult.SUCCESS would it be appropriate to call the method GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(). You don't have to do this. If you had an error then could, for example, send a message from your service to the main activity directing the user to try and update their version.